# Adding two integers

Tags: ios, int

In my game, the speed of the ball increases by a certain number every 15 seconds when the game has started. Right now I have an `int` which is the speed of the ball and the the method:

```
ballSpeed += 1;
```

This works but when I decrease the amount that the ball speed is increased by, which is going to be less than 1, for some reason it doesn't work.

For example, if I do:

```
ballSpeed += .9
```

, for some reason it doesn't work.

I thought that I just couldn't see the difference because it was too small but when i have .99 it still doesn't work and I would be able to tell the difference with that number.

Any answer is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How does one store `1.9` as an integer? (There should be a type error/warning on the `+=` line, but first fix the fundamental design choice.)

Answer (score 1):

You're using integers? .9 is not an integer value so  you'd have to use a different datatype (eg:float) to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Since `ballSpeed` is an integer, it can only take on whole values. So using the code

```
ballSpeed += .9;
```

will cause it to round down, and the end result being `ballSpeed` won't change at all. So 1 is the smallest change you can make.

Comment: Can someone please explain the downvote? Otherwise it's not useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an int to hold a decimal number. Try a float instead of an int.